# Trying to get a script to read a CSV file that is in the same subdirectory

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file saved in my downloads folder. It is the folder I use for any code that needs to be downloaded to Python from somewhere else. I have a CSV file there, and can even open the file in Python, however when I run my script to read it I get an error that the file does not exist. The code looks like this. Just to get the numbers into a list.

```
data = []
with open('file','r') as fout:
    for line in fout:
        data.append(line.split(","))
```

If I replace my csv file with a text file from the same folder, it works, but when I try using this csv file, it's like Python does not know the file is there. What is going on? I have absolutely no clue what to do or why this is happening.

Comment: is your file really named `'file'` with no extension? Beside that, you are missing a `:` after `fout`.  Dont post code that you think "is like your code" - post your real code.

Comment: @PatrickArtner No, the file is location_coordinates.csv . It is an excel spreadsheet with sets of coordinates for the location a phone was in over a period of time. When I input it as the file, Python doesn't see it as existing. However, when I input a different file from the same folder, it works.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily matter if the script and the file are in the same folder. What does matter is what the current directory is when you run the script. You might try extracting the directory of the script from its built-in `__file__` variable and use it create a full path to the data file by joining the directory name with the name of data file.

Comment: Can you add a listing of your folder?

Comment: ok I fixed it. @Martineau thankyou!